# data.table fails when used in parallel

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use data.table in parallel within a function called via plyr.

The following code is working with data.table 1.9.2  and R 2.15.3
but not with data.table 1.9.3 and R 3.0.3

In R 3.0.3 it works only if parallization is turned off by parallel=F

the error I am getting is

```
> Error in do.ply(i) :    task 1 failed - "Check that is.data.table(DT)
> == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")." In addition: Warning
> messages: 1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context:
> ‘.fun(piece, ...)’   2: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect
> context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’
```

The code to reproduce the error message in R 3.0.3 is:

```
library(doSNOW) 
cl<<-makeCluster(2)  
registerDoSNOW(cl)

library(plyr)

myfun=function(x){
  library(data.table)
  mydt=data.table(a=1:12)
  mydt[,b:=a*2]
  mydt

}
gg=ldply(1:2,.fun=myfun,.parallel=T)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: did you try to first load the library before: clusterEvalQ(cl, library(data.table))

Comment: I don't think you can (safely) modify an object by reference in parallel. Is that what you are trying?

Comment: No am not editing the same data.table in parallel. Each parallel Task has ist own individual data.table

Comment: unfortunately I couldn't try the clusterEvalQ - as I have no Access to the Research site at the Moment. Wouldn't library(data.table) do the same?